# Getting arguments where they need to be, with the right scope, in nested piped functions

Tags: r, scope, dplyr, pipe, metaprogramming

I am trying to prepare a variety of summaries from the roughly nine million person records in the Current Population Survey. I have a data set, the CPS, a number of column names that I want to match columns in that data set, and also a vector of parameters; these are meant to enter into a piped series of dplyr transformations at various places along the pipeline. (pipechain? pipe sequence?)

In an effort to achieve the latter I have put the pipes that do the work into a subsidiary function, q_m. My primary function, q_means then calls q_m via do.call with a list of arguments containing the actual arguments of the primary, named with the names of the formals.

In this particular case, I am trying to take the weighted means of adj_inc by adj_inc quantile ranges for each year, but I am trying to understand how to construct this function as a template for calculating weighted grouped statistics in general. I am fairly new at this sort of metaprogramming and am having trouble getting arguments where they need to be with the right scope and state of evaluation.

At the moment I am getting the error message
" Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `.grps` is unknown ", but I have been working with this function for many hours and have achieved a startling diversity of error messages. I am pretty sure that something more fundamental is wrong with my approach, or perhaps several things.

Here is code for a small synthetic data set for reproduciblity:

```
set.seed(1776)
rand<- round(abs(rnorm(20, 1000, 50)))
test_dat <- tibble(year=rep(1:2, times=c(10,10)), adj_inc=30001:30020, 
                   wtsupp=5 * rand)
```

Here are my functions and parameters:

```
q_m     <- function(.dt, .inc, .wts=NULL, 
                    .probs=c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), .grps){
    group_by(.grps)}                        %>%
    mutate(inc2 = .inc,
           inc_q_groups =
             cut(inc2, breaks = wtd.quantile(
               .inc, weights = wts., probs=.probs)))  %>%
      group_by(inc_q_groups, .grps)                          %>%
      summarise(inc_q_means = wtd.mean(
        .inc, weights = .wts)) ->  out
  out
}

var_lst <- with(data=test_dat, list(.inc=adj_inc,.wts=wtsupp, 
                                      .probs=c(0, 0.5, 1)), .grps=year)  

q_means <- function(data = test_dat, var_lst){
  out <- do.call(q_m, c(list(.dt = data), var_lst))
}

test_output  <- q_means(test_dat, var_lst)
```

The answers I expect, assuming non-interpolating versions of quantile, etc., are about 30007.9, 30003.0 for year 1 and 30018.0, 30013.0 for year 2.

Comment: 1. Why `do.call`? 2. Why do all your arguments start with a dot? 3. No `ungroup` (and `if`) necessary; `group_by` does ungrouping automatically. 4. The problem is unrelated to piping. Rather, it’s due to non-standard evaluation. Consequently, the answer to your question is probably related to the ‹rlang› package; see http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Thanks, Konrad! To reply in order: 1. Because it solved an apparently analogous problem in passing parameters and column names to ggplot2 inside a function . 2. Because I have six or seven versions of this function that I am trying to keep from colliding. In retrospect, I should have numbered the variables instead. Are dots a problem? 3. Ah! I have removed the conditional ungroup above, and added .grps to my second group_by.  4. Yes, been doing a lot of experimenting with that. Using what seem to me identical constructions to the vignette, I still get unknown column  errors on .grps.